# Arranging a package to 'reverse URL notation': cant get the main class to run

Tags: java

I arranged my class to reverse URL notation (newb's reaction to a finicky package). I have the `sudoku` directory in my `home`. It hold the binary packages for 'Drools Planner' in `binaries` and my sources. The directory is arranged like

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ ls src/main/java/in/co/technovia/sudoku/
App.class  App.java~  helloworld.class  helloworld.java~
App.java   domain     helloworld.java   solution
```

My classpath points to `.` and the above-mentioned `binaries` of 'Drools Planner'.

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ export | grep CLASSPATH
declare -x CLASSPATH=".:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/binaries/*"
```

---

The `App.java` has this in first line: `package in.co.technovia.sudoku;`

I tried to run the `App` class in the root of my source using the fully qualified package name:

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/sudoku$ java in.co.technovia.sudoku.helloworld
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: in/co/technovia/sudoku/helloworld
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: in.co.technovia.sudoku.helloworld
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
Could not find the main class: in.co.technovia.sudoku.helloworld. Program will exit.
```

---

My question is kinda elementary to Java: how do I run the `java` command or set the `CLASS_PATH` so that the package runs fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class file resides in the same folder as your java file (in your case), so you need to use

```
CLASSPATH=".:/home/jesvin/dev/drools/sudoku/src/main/java"
```

Then, to execute the class, use the command you posted in the question, it should work.

When your code is correctly compiled to the `binaries` directory, you could add this directory to the classpath (not use '*' in the end, because this adds all sub directories instead!). Then, check that there is a directory named `in` inside, as the directory structure must reflect the package structure.

Further, I want to kindly ask you to follow the Java Naming Conventions and always start class names with a capital letter! [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: You mean the `helloworld`? I copied that from elsewhere. I did follow the naming conventions by example

Comment: Yes, I meant that, it confused me in the first place - seems to be a bad hello world example. ^^